# Observing multiple published variable changes inside ObservableObject

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have an `ObservableObject` that contains multiple published variables to handle my app state.
Whenever one of those published variables change, I want to call a function inside my `ObservableObject`. What's the best way to do that?

```swift
class AppModelController: ObservableObject {

    @Published var a: String = "R"
    @Published var b: CGFloat = 0.0
    @Published var c: CGFloat = 0.9
    
    // Call this function whenever a, b or c change
    func check() -> Bool {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing you can do is listen to `objectWillChange`. The catch is that it gets called *before* the object updates. You can use `.receive(on: RunLoop.main)` to get the updates on the next loop, which will reflect the changed values:

```
import Combine

class AppModelController: ObservableObject {

    @Published var a: String = "R"
    @Published var b: CGFloat = 0.0
    @Published var c: CGFloat = 0.9
    
    private var cancellable : AnyCancellable?
    
    init() {
        cancellable = self.objectWillChange
        .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
        .sink { newValue in
            let _ = self.check()
        }
    }
    
    // Call this function whenever a, b or c change
    func check() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @jnpdx. I feel like the pattern that I'm following is not correct. Is there any other way to achieve the same result but in a more "standard" way, or this is what it is? :)

Comment: That's exactly what this is (or the `didSet` method in the other answer). I like this method, personally, since if I added/removed a property, all of it would still work.

Comment: @Hamid you haven't upvoted either answer here. Did you find either answer helpful in any way?

Comment: I'll test both answers today or tomorrow and then will back to here. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use didSet, like this code:

```
class AppModelController: ObservableObject {

    @Published var a: String = "R" { didSet(oldValue) { if (a != oldValue) { check() } } }
    @Published var b: CGFloat = 0.0 { didSet(oldValue) { if (b != oldValue) { check() } } }
    @Published var c: CGFloat = 0.9 { didSet(oldValue) { if (c != oldValue) { check() } } }
    

    func check() {
        
        // Some Work!

    }
}
```